# How to run 2 different computers with one CPU and using VMware

Tags: windows, cpu, multiple-users

I have a good CPU i7 4.4ghz 16 GB ram and 6GB 1060 Graphics card.
Also, I have an old i5 laptop.
Is there any way for the laptop to run using my CPU resources simultaneously?
I am short on funds and my girlfriend needs to work on my PC but we both have work. My CPU is always underutilized. So wondering is it possible to work on my laptop but use my CPU resources such as processing speed and graphics card

Comment: In short, no...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYXW1OFDuN0 so does this guy lie?

Comment: That is about setting up a virtual machine with separate monitors and keyboards. It does not use another computer. You could hook up another monitor and keyboard to your i7 computer but not the ones that are in your i5 laptop.

Comment: I'm not going to watch a 7-minute youtube video to explain something that could have been written in 2 paragraphs of text. Whatever he's doing, it is not what you want. You can use RDC to exploit another computer's CPU… but not whilst someone is already using it, unless you are willing to pay for Enterprise & Server editions of Windows. It would be cheaper to buy another computer. So, to reiterate… in short, No.

Comment: Well in theory if he got as far as setting up a VM, he could remote in - but I'm doubtful that the VM would be that much faster than the i5 unless it was a super early one. You'd also need a windows licence... Passing through graphics cards to a vm from the host is pretty much rocket surgery and black magic at once. There's a lot of specific things that's needed for it to work

Comment: There's also distributed computing… but it's just far, far simpler to say… no. This is not a consumer-level 'quick fix'.

Comment: Lockdown in here so cant a monitor :( . I tried  aster but only thing is I need a display .I cannot use laptops as it is one way

Comment: We have a lot of old questions asking this kind of problem and the best anyone can say is that it is tricky, messy to set up, annoying to keep running, and requires you to know what you are doing. You can set up a VM, attach a keyboard and mouse to the specific VM using USB passthrough, and then put that display on a second monitor, but it has lots of quirks and caveats. If you can't even get a second monitor then this is all a non-starter as sharing a screen would be absolutely painful.

Comment: How about if I install VMware on my Computer. Install secondary OS in VMware and then connect my VMware OS remotely using i5 Laptop. So from Laptop I will be able to control only VM ware OS and on my main PC will use the OS which is already present ? Is it worth the effort or the idea is not worth trying?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the laptop and the desktop on their own in that case? The experience would be nearly identical.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your computers have not been built with your kind of resource sharing in mind. You would need specialized hardware and a suitable operating system to do that.

The mechanism of a transputer do not extend to another separate transputer type computer as far as I know.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transputer